# when drools example is started，it is failed, Why?

Tags: drools

Notes:

- Java must be installed. Get the JRE (http://www.java.com) or the JDK.
- For optimal performance, Java is recommended to be OpenJDK 7 or higher.
- For JDK, the environment variable JAVA_HOME should be set to the JDK installation directory
  For example: set "JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0"
- The working dir should be the directory of this script.

Starting examples app with JDK from environment variable JAVA_HOME (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251)...
13:07:44.382 [main] ERROR o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl.processKieService:131 - Loading failed because There already exists an implementation for service org.drools.core.reteoo.KieComponentFactoryFactory with same priority 0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.drools.dynamic.DynamicServiceRegistrySupplier.get(DynamicServiceRegistrySupplier.java:32)
at org.drools.dynamic.DynamicServiceRegistrySupplier.get(DynamicServiceRegistrySupplier.java:23)
at org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceRegistry$Impl.getServiceRegistry(ServiceRegistry.java:88)
at org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceRegistry$ServiceRegistryHolder.(ServiceRegistry.java:47)
at org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceRegistry.getInstance(ServiceRegistry.java:39)
at org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceRegistry.getService(ServiceRegistry.java:35)
at org.kie.api.KieServices$Factory$LazyHolder.(KieServices.java:358)
at org.kie.api.KieServices$Factory.get(KieServices.java:365)
at org.kie.api.KieServices.get(KieServices.java:349)
at org.drools.examples.DroolsExamplesApp.(DroolsExamplesApp.java:59)
at org.drools.examples.DroolsExamplesApp.main(DroolsExamplesApp.java:52)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to build kie service url = jar:file:/C:/Users/slb0547/Downloads/drools-distribution-7.45.0.Final/drools-distribution-7.45.0.Final/examples/binaries/drools-traits-7.45.0.Final.jar!/META-INF/kie.conf
at org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl.registerConfs(ServiceDiscoveryImpl.java:105)
at org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl.lambda$getServices$1(ServiceDiscoveryImpl.java:83)
at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:159)
at org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl.getServices(ServiceDiscoveryImpl.java:81)
at org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceRegistry$Impl.(ServiceRegistry.java:60)
at org.drools.dynamic.DynamicServiceRegistrySupplier$LazyHolder.(DynamicServiceRegistrySupplier.java:27)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: There already exists an implementation for service org.drools.core.reteoo.KieComponentFactoryFactory with same priority 0
at org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl$PriorityMap.put(ServiceDiscoveryImpl.java:222)
at org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl.processKieService(ServiceDiscoveryImpl.java:124)
at org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl.registerConfs(ServiceDiscoveryImpl.java:101)
... 16 more

Comment: What "drools example" is this?

Comment: Same for me. 
Did you succeed running the example from the distribution zip?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the version to use[drools-distribution-6.5.0.Final](https://www.drools.org/download/download.html) instead of the 7.46.   Now I can play with the examples.
That's not a real answer, but I hope that will be enough for now.